# Silverlight 3.0 - How to access a MainPage control value from an UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to retrieve some control values from the MainPage to an UserControl.
In this UserControl I need to be able to get the Frame.ActualWidth & Frame.ActualHeight values (in this case, the Frame element is in the MainPage and the UserControl is loaded inside a MainPage's Grid via xaml).
Does someone have a sample?
Thank you

Josimari Martarelli 
ESL Sistemas Logísticos 
Silverlight UI Design

### jmartarelli@logfacil.com.br

Answer (score 7):

MainPage m = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;

Answer (score 1):

In instances like this I'll often use have my MainPage class have a public static reference to itself, Instance. I'll set it this "this" in the constructor and then when I need access to the MainPage from down in a user control I'll just call something like:

MainPage.Instance.*Foo*

Answer (score 1):

First I created a static method in the App class that walks up the hierarchy of parents until it finds a match based on name.  This can be used for more than just MainPage. Everything in the hierarchy should be derived from the FrameworkElement class.

```
    public static FrameworkElement GetParentByName(FrameworkElement currentPage, 
string ParentName)
    {

        FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)currentPage.Parent;

        // Walk your way up the chain of Parents until we get a match
        while(fe.GetType().Name != ParentName)
            fe = (FrameworkElement)fe.Parent;

        return fe;

    }
```

Then to use this I just call something like:

MainPage m = (MainPage)App.GetParentByName(this, "MainPage");

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Login page then you have to cast using your login page.

i.e `Login lp = (Login)Application.Current.RootVisual;`
You can use the parameter that you created in login page.