# WP7 Access MainPage Elements

Tags: c#, class, xaml, inheritance, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make a simple Windows Phone 7 Silverlight app. There's the `MainPage.xaml` with some UI elements, and a separate C# class `MyClass.cs` with some code.

**My problem is**: `MyClass` can't access anything contained in `MainPage` (i.e. it doesn't know the UI elements or C# methods exist).

If I try to inherit `MainPage`, the app compiles, but refuses to run:

```
public class MyClass : MainPage
{
   // No good
}
```

If I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728879/silverlight-3-0-how-to-access-a-mainpage-control-value-from-an-usercontrol), then I get an `InvalidCastException` error:

```
public class MyClass
{
  // Also no good
  MainPage m = (MainPage)Application.Current.RootVisual;
}
```

**My question is**: how can I access `MainPage` from a separate class?

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`, I can simply use `myElement.Property` etc. However, this isn't possible in `MyClass`, but I'm not sure why.

I guess there's a simple answer that I'm missing, but I'm really not sure what it is (... C# newbie trying to run before he can walk!?).

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you shouldn't be doing this as this level of coupling is likley to cause issues in the future in terms of reuse and particularly testing.

You could look at having a separate global view model which has the information (properties) you need and is bound to the view model of the main view.

If you need your class to call methods on the view then you could look at a messaging system or similar.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I created some separate global properties as you suggested ([outlined here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/536b644b-bc4b-42c4-8ad5-2458553c3cd3)), set these in `MainPage`, and they work perfectly in `MyClass`. Thanks for the tip!